# Filter data that has invalid field value based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Please consider this script:

```
declare @FirstTable   Table
(
    Name            nvarchar(50), -- Key
    Gender          tinyint,      -- Key   1 for Male, 2 for Female
    DateModified    datetime
)


insert into @FirstTable
Values(N'Tom' , 1, GETDATE()),
      (N'Tom' , 2, GETDATE()),
      (N'Clare' , 2, GETDATE()),
      (N'Lauren' , 1, GETDATE()),
      (N'Sara' , 2, GETDATE()),
      (N'Al' , 1, GETDATE()),
      (N'Kevin' , 1, GETDATE()),
      (N'Meril' , 2, GETDATE())


declare @Movies   Table
(
    Id              int identity(1,1),      
    Name            nvarchar(50),           -- Key
    ActorName       Nvarchar(50),      
    ActorGender     tinyint,
    ReleaseDate     datetime
)


insert into @Movies
Values (N'Movie 1', N'Tom' , 1, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 2', N'Kevin' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 3', N'Meril' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 4', N'Meril' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 5', N'Clare' , 1, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 6', N'Tom' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 7', N'Al' , 1, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 8', N'Sara' , 1, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 9', N'Ben' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 10', N'Viera' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 11', N'George' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 12', N'Frank' , 2, GETDATE()),
       (N'Movie 13', N'Kevin' , 2, GETDATE())

select  Id,     
        tmp.Name, 
        ActorName,      
        ActorGender,
        ReleaseDate
from @Movies tmp inner join @FirstTable gn on tmp.ActorName = gn.Name
where tmp.ActorGender <> gn.Gender
```

I want to select data in `Movie` table that has invalid gender. For example if we assume that `Tom` is a common name between males and females, above query returns `Tom` in result (and it's not correct). Please help me to correct my select statement.

**Edit 1)**
There are some records (Names) that exist only in `Movies` table and there isn't correspondig records in `FirstTable`. I don't want my query returns those records.

Thanks to @Nick, I want this result:

```
Id  Name        ActorName   ActorGender     ReleaseDate
2   Movie 2     Kevin       2               22/12/2018 07:20:14
5   Movie 5     Clare       1               22/12/2018 07:20:14
8   Movie 8     Sara        1               22/12/2018 07:20:14
10  Movie 10    Kevin       2               22/12/2018 07:20:14
```

Thanks

Comment: What if, both genders have the same name? I mean actually, they exist then?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Above query return `Tom` incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Since you don't want to fetch the records where there is a name in the `Movies` table that doesn't exist in the `FirstTable` table, we can filter them out with a `JOIN` on `Movies.ActorName` and `FirstTable.Name`. We can then use the `LEFT JOIN` as before to find the actors whose gender is mismatched:

```
Select  Id,     
        tmp.Name, 
        ActorName,      
        ActorGender,
        ReleaseDate
from Movies tmp 
join FirstTable gn on tmp.ActorName = gn.Name
left join FirstTable gn2 on tmp.ActorName = gn2.Name AND tmp.ActorGender = gn2.Gender
where gn2.Name IS NULL
```

Updated output:

```
Id  Name        ActorName   ActorGender     ReleaseDate
2   Movie 2     Kevin       2               22/12/2018 07:20:14
5   Movie 5     Clare       1               22/12/2018 07:20:14
8   Movie 8     Sara        1               22/12/2018 07:20:14
13  Movie 13    Kevin       2               22/12/2018 07:20:14
```

[Updated demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0f4f4cd9f259d74668816570ed452fe7)

**Original Answer**

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to find entries in the `Movies` table where the `ActorGender` doesn't match the appropriate `Gender` in the `FirstTable` table:

```
Select  Id,     
        tmp.Name, 
        ActorName,      
        ActorGender,
        ReleaseDate
from Movies tmp 
left join FirstTable gn on tmp.ActorName = gn.Name AND tmp.ActorGender = gn.Gender
where gn.Name IS NULL
```

Output:

```
Id  Name        ActorName   ActorGender     ReleaseDate
2   Movie 2     Kevin       2               22/12/2018 07:20:14
5   Movie 5     Clare       1               22/12/2018 07:20:14
8   Movie 8     Sara        1               22/12/2018 07:20:14
10  Movie 10    Kevin       2               22/12/2018 07:20:14
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=fb2cf12b79dfc55fe23357a029b22018)

Comment: Thank it work but I'm so sorry I forget to add some records in `Movies` table. There is some records that only exists in `Movies` table that I don't want query returns that records.

Comment: @Arian see my edit. I think that will solve your problem.